# Piwik Tracking - How to exclude a Single Page from tracking?

Tags: analytics, tracking, web-analytics, matomo

is it possible to exclude a Single Page from Piwik Tracking?
We want to get the Statistics without the tracking of some Subpages on the Website.

Answer (score 0):

You can either not execute javascript code on such site (trackPageView) or exclude it (if it is possible to identify this unique site for example using a query parameter). Excluded parameters can be configured in the websites settings in Piwik.